# Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. | Ionic React Capacitor

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am getting this error while build android project and gradle sync in android studio. I tried to downgrade gradle version to 7.4.0 but still not working

[Package file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NrpCA1L8LokB8H8wTbUO8sgsBTUCMr2-/view?usp=sharing)

here error text

[error text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Om3qhaJo6Wfn8_hqqfhvP1ul8VpuxreH/view?usp=sharing)

Please help me to solve this error. I am using Ionic react.

Comment: Whats your Java version ?

Comment: i have this version in my system: jdk-21

Comment: Can you use java jdk 17 ? Download it and place it to C:\Program Files\Java\..
Than from Andorid Studio point to to that java and build it

Comment: Otherwise in Android Studio . File > Project Structure ? SDK Location > Gradle Settings you can choose Gradle Jdk to jbr-17

Comment: Set jbr-17 but still getting same error.

Comment: Make a build clean, sync gradle files and build in android studio

Comment: Also can you add google-services.json its mentioning on the error

Comment: ok thank you, i will try and update here asap

Comment: I tried but not working. 1) Clean project -> same error

Comment: can you attach again. Did you added google-services.json file ? If yes should be another error.

Comment: i did not attached google file, let me add and i will will update in few minutes

Comment: Did you solve the problem?